# How to return the most ordered item for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I am trying to return the most ordered product per month, of the year 2007.  I would like to see the name of the product, how many of them where ordered that month, and the month.  I am using the AdventureWorks2012 database.  I have tried a few different ways but each time multiple product orders are returned for the same month, instead of the one product that had the most order quantity that month.  Sorry if this is not clear.  I am trying to test myself so I make up my own questions and try to answer them.  If anyone knows a site that have questions and answers like this so I can verify that would be super helpful!  Thanks for any help.  Here is the farthest I have been able to get with the query.

```
WITH     Ord2007Sum
AS       (SELECT   sum(od.orderqty) AS sorder,
                   od.productid,
                   oh.orderdate,
                   od.SalesOrderID
          FROM     Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS od
                   INNER JOIN
                   sales.SalesOrderHeader AS oh
                   ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
          WHERE    year(oh.OrderDate) = 2007
          GROUP BY ProductID, oh.OrderDate, od.SalesOrderID)
SELECT   max(sorder),
         s.productid,
         month(h.orderdate) AS morder --, s.salesorderid
FROM     Ord2007Sum AS s
         INNER JOIN
         sales.SalesOrderheader AS h
         ON s.OrderDate = h.OrderDate
GROUP BY s.ProductID, month(h.orderdate)
ORDER BY morder;
```

Comment: Check out the ROW_NUMBER() function, tons of examples on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Make a CTE that groups our products by month and creates a sum

```
;WITH OrderRows AS
(
    SELECT
        od.ProductId, 
        MONTH(oh.OrderDate) SalesMonth,
        SUM(od.orderqty) OVER (PARTITION BY od.ProductId, MONTH(oh.OrderDate) ORDER BY oh.OrderDate) ProdMonthSum
    FROM SalesOrderDetail AS od
    INNER JOIN SalesOrderHeader AS oh
        ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
    WHERE year(oh.OrderDate) = 2007
),
```

Make a simple numbers table to break out each month of the year

```
Months AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS MonthNum UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 
    UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 
    UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12
)
```

We query our months table against the data and select the top product for each month based on the sum

```
SELECT 
    m.MonthNum,
    d.ProductID,
    d.ProdMonthSum
FROM Months m
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 r.ProductID, r.ProdMonthSum 
    FROM OrderRows r
    WHERE r.SalesMonth = m.MonthNum
    ORDER BY ProdMonthSum DESC
) d
```

Answer (score 0):

Your group by statement should not include `oh.OrderDate, od.SalesOrderID` because this will aggregate your data to the incorrect level. You want the ProductID that was most commonly sold per month so the group by conditions become `ProductID, datepart(mm,oh.OrderDate)`. As Andrew suggested the Row_Number function is useful in this case as it lets you create a key that is ordered by month and sorder and which resets each month. Finally in the outer query limits the results to the first instance (which is the highest quantity)for each month.

```
WITH     Ord2007Sum 
AS(
        SELECT  sum(od.orderqty) AS sorder,
                od.productid,
                datepart(mm,oh.OrderDate) AS 'Month'
                row_number() over (partition by datepart(mm,oh.OrderDate)
                                    Order by datepart(mm,oh.OrderDate)desc, sorder desc) row
        FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS od
                INNER JOIN
                sales.SalesOrderHeader AS oh
             ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
        WHERE    datepart(yyyy,oh.OrderDate) = 2007
        GROUP BY ProductID, datepart(mm,oh.OrderDate)
    )

SELECT  productid,
        sorder,
        [month]
FROM    Ord2007Sum 
WHERE   row =1
```